# Problems plotting a 2-D colour map in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, colormap

I am a Matlab beginner trying to do a project.

I want to plot a 2-D colour map, of the variable Et1in as a function of x and z (as in x and z are coordinates of the map, and Et1in is what the color represent), which I had problem plotting, and the problem is demonstrated with code as below:

Here I create a meshgrid for x,z for using surf function later to plot the color map

```
[x,z] = meshgrid(0:100:600,0:100:600);
mm = size(z);
```

So the function I want to plot (Et1in) is actually the first element of a 2 by 1 matrix Et1left calculated as below (kzia, GammaT1, Rs1,Ts1... are just constants defined previously):

```
M1 = [1/Ts1,Rs1/Ts1;Rs1/Ts1,1/Ts1];                       
P1 = [exp(1i*delta1),0; 0,exp(-1i*delta1)];                
M2 = [1/Ts2,Rs2/Ts2;Rs2/Ts2,1/Ts2];

Et1in = zeros(7,7)
for z2 = 3:mm(1)
    for x2 = 3:mm(1)
        Et1left = inv(P1)*[exp(-1i*kzia*z(z2));GammaT1*exp(-1i*kzia*z(z2))];
        Et1in = Et1left(1,1)*exp(-1i*kxia*x(x2));
    end
end
```

and to plot the color map, I used:

```
Eplot = zeros(size(x)) + real(Et1in)

figure;
surf(x,z,Eplot,'EdgeColor','None');
view(2);
xlabel('x','fontsize',20);
ylabel('z','fontsize',20);
colormap jet;
```

So the problem is, **Et1left** is calculated by multiplying a 2 by 2 matrix:

```
(inv(P1))
```

With a 2 by 1 matrix:

```
[exp(-1i*kzia*z(z2));GammaT1*exp(-1i*kzia*z(z2))],
```

where x and z are variables in the 2 by 1 matrix component.

So **if I don't use for loop**, then Matlab returns the error says the matrix dimension doesn't agree, because x and z are meshgrid, which means the dimension matrix:

```
[exp(-1i*kzia*z(z2));GammaT1*exp(-1i*kzia*z(z2))]
```

is not 2 by 1 any more, because x and z are matrix themselves created by the meshgrid function.

If I **do use the for loop**, then the function I plot is just the same value everywhere, because the value of Et1in Matlab overwrite the value of Et1in for every new value generated by for loop, so the map plotted is just the last value generated by the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in understanding you want to keep the value of `Et1in` as it goes through the loop?

If so change the

```
Et1in = Et1left(1,1)*exp(-1i*kxia*x(x2));
```

to

```
Et1in(x2, z2) = Et1left(1,1)*exp(-1i*kxia*x(x2));
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Only thing is, it run super slowly, is there anyway to improve the speed, because for the actual project, I need a meshgrid of at least 100 points, instead only 7 points, then it runs forever and I have to terminate it before it yields a outcome

Comment: A couple of ideas are to get rid of `inv` and replace it with ``\``. Or better do the matrix calculation and simplify to minimize order of operations